# Constructing queries by using @Query annotation in Jpa repo

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

This is my logic for a query:

```
String customQuery = "";
customQuery = customQuery + "select * from Customer c where";

if (targetGroupDto.getGender() != null && !targetGroupDto.getGender().isEmpty()) {
    customQuery = customQuery + " c.gender = " + targetGroupDto.getGender();
    if (targetGroupDto.getAge() != 0
        || (targetGroupDto.getCity() != null && !targetGroupDto.getCity().isEmpty())
        || (targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty())) {
        customQuery = customQuery + " and ";
    }
}

if (targetGroupDto.getAge() != 0) {
    customQuery = customQuery + " c.age = " + targetGroupDto.getAge();
    if ((targetGroupDto.getCity() != null && !targetGroupDto.getCity().isEmpty())
        || (targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty())) {
        customQuery = customQuery + " and ";
    }
}

if (targetGroupDto.getCity() != null && !targetGroupDto.getCity().isEmpty()) {
    customQuery = customQuery + " c.city = " + targetGroupDto.getCity();
    if ((targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty())) {
        customQuery = customQuery + " and ";
    }
}

if (targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty()) {
    customQuery = customQuery + " c.state = " + targetGroupDto.getState();
}
```

**

> This is a class where i m writing the query and i am calling this
>   method in my service class

**

```
 @Transactional
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Set<Customer> filterCustomers(TargetGroupDto targetGroupDto) {

        //CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        //CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
        //Root<Customer> customer = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);


        Query query;
        String customQuery = "";
        customQuery = customQuery + "select * from Customer c where";

        if (targetGroupDto.getGender() != null && !targetGroupDto.getGender().isEmpty()) {
            customQuery = customQuery + " c.gender = " + targetGroupDto.getGender();
            if (targetGroupDto.getAge() != 0
                    || (targetGroupDto.getCity() != null && !targetGroupDto.getCity().isEmpty())
                    || (targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty())) {
                customQuery = customQuery + " and ";
            }
        }

        if (targetGroupDto.getAge() != 0) {
            customQuery = customQuery + " c.age = " + targetGroupDto.getAge();
            if ((targetGroupDto.getCity() != null && !targetGroupDto.getCity().isEmpty())
                    || (targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty())) {
                customQuery = customQuery + " and ";
            }
        }
        if (targetGroupDto.getCity() != null && !targetGroupDto.getCity().isEmpty()) {
            customQuery = customQuery + " c.city = " + targetGroupDto.getCity();
            if ((targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty())) {
                customQuery = customQuery + " and ";
            }
        }

        if (targetGroupDto.getState() != null && !targetGroupDto.getState().isEmpty()) {
            customQuery = customQuery + " c.state = " + targetGroupDto.getState();
        }
        query = getEntityManager().createQuery(customQuery);
        List<Customer> customers = query.getResultList();
        Set<Customer> results = new HashSet<Customer>(customers);

        return results;
    }
```

**

> > > I get this Null Pointer Exception on calling this method  java.lang.NullPointerException  at
> > >       com.thoughtclan.segmentationofcustomers.service.SocServiceImpl.filterDetails(SocServiceImpl.java:102)
> > >         at
> > >       com.thoughtclan.segmentationofcustomers.controller.SegmentationOfCustomersController.filterDetails(SegmentationOfCustomersController.java:73)
>
> SegmentationOfCustomersController.java:73)->           customers =
>   socService.filterDetails(targetGroupDto);
>
> SocServiceImpl.java:102)->        filteredCustomers =
>   customerRepositoryImpl.filterCustomers(targetGroupDto);
>
> > **

Comment: That is invalid JPQL. It is SQL. Hence you need to put "nativeQuery" on it

Comment: I have created a separate class for executing queries

Comment: and what? You have a method in the question that generates SQL (`SELECT * ...`), and you dump it into `createQuery` which takes in JPQL.

Comment: yeah something like that..is this  a wrong way of doing it??

Comment: Errm, yes. `createQuery` takes in JPQL (as I said above). `createNativeQuery` takes in SQL (as any JPA docs tell you).

Comment: got it thanks.....